# Android Fairphone 3+ appears in Photos but no photos

Tags: photos.app, android

When I connect my phone (Fairphone 3+ with Android 10) to my Macbook (with Catalina) and choose "PTP" in the phone's USB settings, the phone appears as "FP3" in the Devices section of Photos, but when I click on it Photos shows "No Photos" even though there are photos on the phone (that show up in the Android Photos app). Is there something I can change on the phone or on the Mac to get the photos to show up?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think Macs can't read Android devices properly and you need https://www.android.com/filetransfer/

Comment: @X_841 it worked with my previous phone. Finder can't do MTP file transfers but I'm pretty sure Photos can do PTP